# C++ Linked List next pointer not moving

Tags: c++, linked-list

My code for singly linked list is as follow:
where My Node has these `getters` and `setters` `GetNext()` and `SetNext()` `GetData()` and `SetData()`

```
template <class T>
void MyList<T>::Add(const T& data){

    Node<T> *t = new Node<T>(data); // create node with givin data and set the next to null
    Node<T> *tmp = head;
    if (head == nullptr)
    {
        head = t;
    }
    else
    {
        while (tmp != nullptr)
        {
            cout << tmp->GetData()<< "\n";

            tmp = tmp->GetNext(); // GetNext() returns Node<T>* next pointer
        }

        tmp = t;
    }
}
```

I did not overload any equal operator.

Why the assignement `tmp = tmp->GetNext();`  is never move to the next pointer !!!!

---

## Minimal Complete Example

Here is a minimal example which shows (when run) that only "42" gets added
but not the second element ("12").

```cpp
#include <iostream>

template <typename T> class Node {
public:
  Node<T>(const T &data) : data_(data) {}
  Node<T> *GetNext() const { return next_; }
  T GetData() const { return data_; }

private:
  Node<T> *next_{nullptr};
  T data_{};
};

template <class T> class MyList {
public:
  void Add(const T &data) {
    Node<T> *t = new Node<T>(
        data); // create node with givin data and set the next to null
    Node<T> *tmp = head;
    if (head == nullptr) {
      head = t;
    } else {
      while (tmp != nullptr) {
        std::cout << tmp->GetData() << "\n";
        tmp = tmp->GetNext(); // GetNext() returns Node<T>* next pointer
      }
      tmp = t;
    }
  }

private:
  Node<T> *head{nullptr};
};

int main() {
  MyList<int> list;
  list.Add(42);
  list.Add(12);
}
```

Here is a link for this example on Godbolt: https://godbolt.org/z/KTwwGT

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I did update it could you please explain what is wrong

Comment: That is not a [mcve].  Describing what the code is supposed to do is not enough.  We need to actually see those functions.

Comment: There is no non-null next pointer because you never assign a non-null value to one and your list never has more than one node.

Comment: @molbdnilo what do you mean ?

Comment: To make it a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), try making your code compile here and show the issue:  https://godbolt.org/z/AijZeL

Comment: @Unapiedra the code is very very clear, unless you want to show the whole code that is `unnecessary` the code has node instead of I do next I use get and set thats it

Comment: In case `tmp->GetNext()` is `nullptr` you need to set `tmp->SetNext()` instead of assigning it to `tmp` and then using `temp = t`

Comment: @rebiccaangy Where do you think you set the next pointer of a node to something that's not null? Read the code and look for uses of `SetNext`.

Comment: @kuo can you show how to fix that ???

Comment: @molbdnilo and how I am gonna fix that ?

Comment: @rebiccaangy, `tmp = tmp->GetNext();` will get the next pointer of last accessed node. But after that if you change `tmp` it will not affect the next pointer of  previous node. You need to check if next pointer is nullptr then you should set the next pointer before you assign it to `tmp`

Comment: @kuro can you please write a code how to fox it ??

Comment: @Unapiedra HOW to Fix i please ??

Comment: @rebiccaangy give me a bit of time.

Answer (score 0):

The logic of your code is wrong. Look at `Node`. `_next` is always set to nullptr (in the constructor) and it never gets set to anything else. So because `_next` is always equal to nullptr `GetNext` always returns `nullptr`.

First you need to add a `SetNext` method to `Node`.

```
template <typename T> class Node {
public:
  Node<T>(const T &data) : data_(data) {}
  Node<T> *GetNext() const { return next_; }
  void SetNext(Node<T> *next) { next_ = next; }
  T GetData() const { return data_; }

private:
  Node<T> *next_{nullptr};
  T data_{};
};
```

Then you need to write a version of `Add` that uses `SetNext` to link the new node into the list.

```
void Add(const T &data) {
    Node<T> *new_node = new Node<T>(data);
    if (head == nullptr) {
        // list is empty, set head to the new node
        head = new_node;
    } else {
        // find the last node, so we can add the new node to it
        Node<T> last = head;
        while (last->GetNext() != nullptr) {
            last = last->GetNext();
        }
        last->SetNext(new_node);
    }
}
```

Untested code

Answer (score 0):

https://godbolt.org/z/CdD32y

```cpp
#include <cassert>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>

template <typename T> struct Node {
public:
  Node<T>(const T &_data) : data(_data) {}

  Node<T> *next{nullptr};
  T data{};
};

template <class T> class MyList {

private:
  Node<T> *head{nullptr};

public:
  class iterator : public std::iterator<std::input_iterator_tag, T> {
    Node<T> *node_ptr_{nullptr};

  public:
    explicit iterator(Node<T> *node_ptr) : node_ptr_(node_ptr) {}
    iterator &operator++() {
      assert(node_ptr_);
      node_ptr_ = node_ptr_->next;
      return *this;
    }
    bool operator==(iterator other) const {
      return node_ptr_ == other.node_ptr_;
    }
    bool operator!=(iterator other) const { return !(*this == other); }
    T operator*() const { return node_ptr_->data; }
  };
  iterator begin() { return iterator(head); }
  iterator end() { return iterator(nullptr); }

  void Add(const T &data) {
    Node<T> *ptr = head;
    if (!ptr) {
      head = new Node<T>(data);
      return;
    }
    while (ptr->next) {
      ptr = ptr->next;
    }
    ptr->next = new Node<T>(data);
  }
};

int main() {
  MyList<int> list;
  list.Add(42);
  list.Add(12);

  // Let's check that the right values are in `list`.
  for (const auto &value : list) {
    std::cout << value << '\n';
  }
}
```